# 16.04.1 Install Welcome Screen Zoomed In / Incorrect Resolution

Tags: display-resolution

Hopefully this will be an easy fix. I'm attempting to install  16.04.1 32-bit on a Dell Precision T3400 tower with video output to the VGA port of a Sanyo flat screen tv. It boots the DVD fine and the Ubuntu splash screen displays fine (i.e. the word Ubuntu is centered on the screen). However when the Welcome screen appears where you select your language, whether to try or install, etc., it's as though you can only see the upper left quarter of the full screen.  Moving the mouse doesn't scroll the display. I managed to click blindly and get to the network setup screen but couldn't get past that point.

Thus my question - it's  (I suspect) somehow detecting the wrong resolution. Is there any way to force what resolution to use? It's booting from the DVD so there's no configuration file I can edit, but if such a file exists on the disc I can open it in Windows and burn a new disc.

Comment: It sounds more like your TV is set to Zoom mode or something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've tried setting the resolution on your TV with no luck then your next choice is to change the resolution via software with **the Ubuntu Live CD** Advanced Options.

### **Ubuntu CD Advanced Welcome Page Options**

As the CD boots, you can gain access to the advanced page and its options by pressing any key when the small logo appears at the bottom of your screen.

A menu appears with 5 options:

1. Try Ubuntu without installing.
2. Install Ubuntu.
3. Check for disk defects.
4. Test memory.
5. Boot from first hard disk.

At the bottom of the screen is a legend indicating to press <kbd>F6</kbd> to override boot options. Here you are presented with the boot command line options where you can override the screen resolutions.

### **Screen Resolutions**

There are a number of resolutions you can try:

```
Colour depth    640x480 800x600 1024x768    1280x1024   1400x1050   1600x1200
  8 (256)         769     771      773         775  
 15 (32K)         784     787      790         793  
 16 (65K)         785     788      791         794         834         884
 24 (16M)         786     789      792         795
```

If you wanted **SVGA** (800x600) 256 colors you would enter `VGA=771` on the boot command line.

Besides SVGA you can try vanilla **VGA** with option `VGA=769`. Alternatively if your TV is set for max resolution of **1600x1200** with `VGA=864`. Watching the screen change you can decide which is best for you.

There might be other tricks but this is the easiest place to start.